# Constructing and sending binary data over network

Tags: c++, networking, binary, minecraft

I am creating a command-line client for minecraft. There is a full spec on the protocol that can be found here: http://mc.kev009.com/Protocol. To answer your question beforehand, yes I am a bit of a C++ noob.

I have various issues in implementing this protocol, of which each critical.

1. The protocol says that all types are big-endian. I have no idea how I should check whether my data is little-endian and if yes how to convert to big-endian.
2. The string datatype is a bit weird one. It's a modified UTF-8 string which is preceded by a short containing the string length. I have no idea how I should pack this into a simple char[] array nor how to convert my simple strings into modified UTF-8 ones.
3. Even if I knew how to convert my data to big-endian and create modified UTF-8 strings I still don't know how to pack this up into a char[] array and send this as a package. All I have done before is simple HTTP networking which is plain ASCII.

Explanations, links, related function names and short snippets much appreciated!

**EDIT**

1 and 3 is answered now. 1 is answered below by user470379. 3 is answered by this AWESOME thread that explains what I want to do very well: [http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/68196-sending-non-char*-data.html](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/68196-sending-non-char%2a-data.html) I'm not sure about the modified UTF-8 yet though.

Comment: There are already a lot of good questions and answers regarding endianness on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A traditional approach is to define a C++ message structure for each protocol message and implement serialization and deserialization functions for it. For example [Login Request](http://mc.kev009.com/Protocol#Login_Request_.280x01.29) can be represented like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>

struct LoginRequest
{
    int32_t protocol_version;
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    int64_t map_seed;
    int8_t dimension;
};
```

Now serialization functions are required. First it needs serialization functions for integers and strings, since these are the types of members in `LoginRequest`.

Integer serialization functions need to do conversions to and from big-endian representation. Since members of the message are copied to and from the buffer, the reversal of the byte order can be done while copying:

```
#include <boost/detail/endian.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

#ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN

    inline void xcopy(void* dst, void const* src, size_t n)
    {
        char const* csrc = static_cast<char const*>(src);
        std::reverse_copy(csrc, csrc + n, static_cast<char*>(dst));
    }

#elif defined(BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN)

    inline void xcopy(void* dst, void const* src, size_t n)
    {
        char const* csrc = static_cast<char const*>(src);
        std::copy(csrc, csrc + n, static_cast<char*>(dst));
    }

#endif

// serialize an integer in big-endian format
// returns one past the last written byte, or >buf_end if would overflow
template<class T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, char*>::type serialize(T val, char* buf_beg, char* buf_end)
{
    char* p = buf_beg + sizeof(T);
    if(p <= buf_end)
        xcopy(buf_beg, &val, sizeof(T));
    return p;
}

// deserialize an integer from big-endian format
// returns one past the last written byte, or >buf_end if would underflow (incomplete message)
template<class T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, char const*>::type deserialize(T& val, char const* buf_beg, char const* buf_end)
{
    char const* p = buf_beg + sizeof(T);
    if(p <= buf_end)
        xcopy(&val, buf_beg, sizeof(T));
    return p;
}
```

And for strings (handling [modified UTF-8 the same way as asciiz strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8)):

```
// serialize a UTF-8 string
// returns one past the last written byte, or >buf_end if would overflow
char* serialize(std::string const& val, char* buf_beg, char* buf_end)
{
    int16_t len = val.size();
    buf_beg = serialize(len, buf_beg, buf_end);
    char* p = buf_beg + len;
    if(p <= buf_end)
        memcpy(buf_beg, val.data(), len);
    return p;
}

// deserialize a UTF-8 string
// returns one past the last written byte, or >buf_end if would underflow (incomplete message)
char const* deserialize(std::string& val, char const* buf_beg, char const* buf_end)
{
    int16_t len;
    buf_beg = deserialize(len, buf_beg, buf_end);
    if(buf_beg > buf_end)
        return buf_beg; // incomplete message
    char const* p = buf_beg + len;
    if(p <= buf_end)
        val.assign(buf_beg, p);
    return p;
}
```

And a couple of helper functors:

```
struct Serializer
{
    template<class T>
    char* operator()(T const& val, char* buf_beg, char* buf_end)
    {
        return serialize(val, buf_beg, buf_end);
    }
};

struct Deserializer
{
    template<class T>
    char const* operator()(T& val, char const* buf_beg, char const* buf_end)
    {
        return deserialize(val, buf_beg, buf_end);
    }
};
```

Now using these primitive functions we can readily serialize and deserialize `LoginRequest` message:

```
template<class Iterator, class Functor>
Iterator do_io(LoginRequest& msg, Iterator buf_beg, Iterator buf_end, Functor f)
{
    buf_beg = f(msg.protocol_version, buf_beg, buf_end);
    buf_beg = f(msg.username, buf_beg, buf_end);
    buf_beg = f(msg.password, buf_beg, buf_end);
    buf_beg = f(msg.map_seed, buf_beg, buf_end);
    buf_beg = f(msg.dimension, buf_beg, buf_end);
    return buf_beg;
}

char* serialize(LoginRequest const& msg, char* buf_beg, char* buf_end)
{
    return do_io(const_cast<LoginRequest&>(msg), buf_beg, buf_end, Serializer());
}

char const* deserialize(LoginRequest& msg, char const* buf_beg, char const* buf_end)
{
    return do_io(msg, buf_beg, buf_end, Deserializer());
}
```

Using the helper functors above and representing input/output buffers as `char` iterator ranges only one function template is required to do both serialization and deserialization of the message.

And putting all together, usage:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[0x100];
    char* buf_beg = buf;
    char* buf_end = buf + sizeof buf;

    LoginRequest msg;

    char* msg_end_1 = serialize(msg, buf, buf_end);
    if(msg_end_1 > buf_end)
        ; // more buffer space required to serialize the message

    char const* msg_end_2 = deserialize(msg, buf_beg, buf_end);
    if(msg_end_2 > buf_end)
        ; // incomplete message, more data required
}
```

Comment: You. Sir. Are. Awesome. Enjoy your +25.

Comment: Though wouldn't using the default network endian functions be better? http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

Comment: There are no 64-bit versions of hton-functions, only 16 and 32. `betoh` and `hoteb` are just different Linux-specific names for the same functionality with 64-bit integer support. You may as well avoid using them altogether by using a reversing version of `memcpy()` when converting big-endian to little-endian and back.

Comment: A reversing version of `memcpy()` would destruct everything if the host OS is big-endian already. And you are right, there are no 64 bit versions, but I don't need those for this program.

Comment: Use reversing version of `memcpy()` **only when converting big-endian to little-endian**, when there is no conversion (i.e. big-endian to big-endian) use straight forward `memcpy()`. Host byte-order can be detected at preprocessing or compile time.

Comment: Updated byte order reversal to be more portable.

Comment: @Maxim: Thanks! That infact is a LOT better then to use non-portable legacy C functions like htobe16 or self-constructed bit masks.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you'll need to use [`ntohs`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) and friends. Use the `*s` (short) versions for 16-bit integers, and the `*l` (long) versions for 32-bit integers. The `hton*` (host to network) will convert outgoing data to big-endian independently of the endianness of the platform you're on, and `ntoh*` (network to host) will convert incoming data back (again, independent of platform endianness)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to store those int's in a char[] array by splitting up in bytes?

Answer (score 1):

off the top of my head...

```
const char* s;  // the string you want to send
short len = strlen(s);

// allocate a buffer with enough room for the length info and the string
char* xfer = new char[ len + sizeof(short) ];

// copy the length info into the start of the buffer
// note:  you need to hanle endian-ness of the short here.
memcpy(xfer, &len, sizeof(short));

// copy the string into the buffer
strncpy(xfer + sizeof(short), s, len);

// now xfer is the string you want to send across the wire.
// it starts with a short to identify its length.
// it is NOT null-terminated.
```

Comment: You really should declare two variables for the length, one as a size_t to hold the real length; or at least make `len` an unsigned short. As it stands right now, this code will fail spectacularly when `strlen(s) % 65536 > 32768`.

Comment: good point.  Or we could just do `short len = boost::numeric_cast<short>(strlen(s));` which will throw an exception if it doesn't fit in a short.