# How to send/receive e.g. images(.png, .jpg)

Tags: c++, image, sockets, networking, sfml

First of all I would like to point out, that I am currently trying to improve my networking skills. I learned how to make a simple server/client program, sending strings and receiving them. I am using SFML to create the TCP/UDP sockets.

Just the basic stuff...

Now I would like to know how you can send other stuff than strings, e.g. an image, or any kind of data type. Unfortunately I could not find any resources considering this section.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "binary". If you search for "c++ binary data over network" on Google, you will find more than 300000 results.

Comment: You can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303617/constructing-and-sending-binary-data-over-network  the OP has editid his question with a reference to a step by step guide

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial on using sockets in a linux environment:  http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html  :

- Chapter 5 details every operation. You'll be interested in send() and recv(), but the preparation of the socet is also explained.
- Chapter 6 has small examples, with a server and a client programme.

For windows,  microsoft has also a nice tutorial here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But if you want a portable solution, you may want to have a closer look at boost::asio here:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html  .  There are also examples and tutorials.  The key to your issue is [ip::tcp::socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) which allows you to read/wrtie data from/to a socket.